# My xml contains a String with the name of the enum constant the setter should pick when using JAXB, but fails to do so. How is this done right?

Tags: java, java-8, jaxb

I am using Java 8's embedded JAXB to generate a catalogue/registry of Java objects from a xml configuration file. One attribute of the element representing the class of objects to import is a string that corresponds to the name of an enum constant on the java side (not an enum inside the xml). My intention was, that on import JAXB calls the corresponding setter, hands over the String as Partameter and the setter then picks the correct constant from the enum and assigns it to the Java Object's respective field.

When I execute the code, the catalogue is read in, and all other data is set correctly, just the field that should contain the enum constant remains null. I tried to put a System.out inside that setter, and it seems it is not called. Please help me to understand what I am doing wrong and how to get the result I want.

A small sample XML "/PhaserType.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tns:PhaserTypes xmlns:tns="http://my.example.org/PhaserTypeSchema"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://my.example.org/PhaserTypeSchema PhaserTypeSchema.xsd ">
  <tns:PhaserType name="FH-3"  range="20" power="5"  chart="A" />
  <tns:PhaserType name="FH-10" range="20" power="7"  chart="B" />
  <tns:PhaserType name="FH-11" range="24" power="10" chart="C" />
</tns:PhaserTypes>
```

The Java class file "/org/example/my/PhaserType.java" for the catalogue objects, the setter in question is `setChart(String chartName)`:

```
package org.example.my;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "PhaserType")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public class PhaserType
{
    private static final Map<String, PhaserType> PHASER_TYPE_REGISTRY = new HashMap<>();
    private String name;
    private int range;
    private int power;
    private Chart chart;

    // init phaser type registry on class load
    static 
    {
        File configFile = getConfigFile();
        JAXBContext jaxbContext;

        try
        {
          jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(PhaserTypes.class);        
         
          Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
         
          PhaserTypes phaserTypes = (PhaserTypes) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(configFile);
          
          for (PhaserType type : phaserTypes.getPhaserTypes())
          {
              PHASER_TYPE_REGISTRY.put(type.getName(), type);
          }
        }
        catch (JAXBException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.toString(), e);
        }           
    }

    private static File getConfigFile()
    {
        ClassLoader loader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
        URL resource = loader.getResource("PhaserType.xml");
        if (resource == null)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("resource PhaserType.xml not found");
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                return new File(resource.toURI());
            }
            catch (URISyntaxException e)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException(e.toString(), e);
            }
        }
    }

    public static Optional<PhaserType> get(String name)
    {
        Optional<PhaserType> result;
        if (PHASER_TYPE_REGISTRY.containsKey(name))
        {
            result = Optional.of(PHASER_TYPE_REGISTRY.get(name));
        }
        else
        {
            result = Optional.empty();
        }
        return result;
    }

    private PhaserType()
    {
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    @XmlAttribute(name="name")
    private void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the range
     */
    public int getRange()
    {
        return range;
    }

    /**
     * @param range the range to set
     */
    @XmlAttribute(name="range")
    private void setRange(int range)
    {
        this.range = range;
    }

    /**
     * @return the power
     */
    public int getPower()
    {
        return power;
    }

    /**
     * @param power the power to set
     */
    @XmlAttribute(name="power")
    private void setPower(int power)
    {
        this.power = power;
    }

    /**
     * @return the chart
     */
    public Chart getChart()
    {
        return chart;
    }

    /**
     * @param chart the chart to set
     */
    @XmlAttribute(name="chart")
    private void setChart(String chartName)
    {
        this.chart = Chart.valueOf(chartName);
    }
    
    @XmlRootElement(name = "PhaserTypes")
    @XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    private static class PhaserTypes 
    {
        @XmlElement(name = "PhaserType")
        private List<PhaserType> phaserTypes = null;
     
        public List<PhaserType> getPhaserTypes()
        {
            return phaserTypes;
        }
    }
}
```

And in case you need additional information or want to set up the project yourself, I wanted to append the xsd, the package-info.java, the enum and a small Main to try it out. But when I did this, stackoverflow tells me "Your question appears to be spam" and does not allow me to post.